# React: Transitions are cut after element re-render further in the elements array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

While creating a swap list in React, I encountered a strange transition bug. The way the list works is simple: you click on an element (A), its background transitions to a lighter color, then on another (B), they swap places, and element A, now on a new position, transitions back to the original color.

At least that's what's happens when element A has a higher index then element B. When it's the other way round, the transition after the swap is cut.

I managed to find a workaround using `window.requestAnimationFrame`, but it's not perfect. The state of the transition isn't preserved, which means that it transitions back always from the full light color. It doesn't matter that much here, but it's an issue in my other project. Sometimes the transitions are also cut anyway.

The code is simple. The thing to note is that elements preserve their keys after the swap. I created [a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-shaw-o76zg) for you to play around.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Item = props => {
  let classes = "item";

  if (props.selected) {
    classes += " selected";
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1);

  const select = index => {
    setSelected(index);
  };

  const swap = index => {
    const newList = [...list];
    [newList[index], newList[selected]] = [newList[selected], newList[index]];
    setList(newList);
    setSelected(-1);
  };

  // The workaround that kind of works, but is not perfect.
  // const swap = index => {
  //   const newList = [...list];
  //   [newList[index], newList[selected]] = [newList[selected], newList[index]];
  //   setList(newList);

  //   window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  //     setSelected(index);
  //     window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  //       setSelected(-1);
  //     });
  //   });
  // };

  const onClick = selected < 0 ? select : swap;

  const items = list.map((value, index) => (
    <Item
      key={value}
      value={value}
      selected={selected === index}
      onClick={onClick.bind(this, index)}
    />
  ));

  return <div className="list">{items}</div>;
}
```

Here are the key css rules:

```
.item {
  background: #0b7189; // darker
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.item.selected {
  background-color: #228cdb; //lighter
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that is more reliable than my workaround.

All help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

[I've made three changes in your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sinoussi-k2bpp?fontsize=14), so upon swapping the highlighted box remains the same one, then turns off:

1. Added the line `setSelected(index);` inside the swap function.
2. Added a `setTimeout` in order to delay the colour change.
3. Changed the `key` inside the `map` loop to the `index` value, as it must be unique and therefore it's just a better practice to use the index.

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1);

  const select = index => {
    setSelected(index);
  };

  const swap = index => {
    const newList = [...list];
    [newList[index], newList[selected]] = [newList[selected], newList[index]];
    setList(newList);

    // This was added in order to keep the highlight after swap.
    // Note that it takes a second to take place
    setSelected(index);

    // And this was added in order to allow the colour to lighten,
    // before returning to the original colour
    setTimeout(() => setSelected(-1), 1000);
  };

  const onClick = selected < 0 ? select : swap;

  const items = list.map((value, index) => (
    <Item
      key={index}
      value={value}
      selected={selected === index}
      onClick={onClick.bind(this, index)}
    />
  ));

  return <div className="list">{items}</div>;
}
```

Comment: But you've also added a 1s timeout. It's not how I want it to work, and it's also a hack. Appreciate the help, though. :)

Comment: @AtomHeart sorry for that. I innocently forgot to mention that :O  However why do you think using `setTimeout` is a hack? What other behaviour are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Go to my code sandbox and swap element of index 1 with an element of index 0 (in that order). That's the behavior I want to achieve. Then start with index 0, and swap for index 1 -- that's the problem, no transition after swap.

Comment: It would be a hack if I used it to achieve the behavior I want, i.e. set it to 0ms.